# Is it possible to alter a record in rails, without first reading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to alter a record, but I don't want to read it out of the database first, because frankly I don't see the point. It's huge and across a network that is slow and expensive.
Can it be done (easily)?

Lets say I have a record with 100 fields (for arguments sake) and I want to alter one field in the table.  I have a really bad connection to the database (this is true) because it's housed on a different box and there's nothing I can do to change this.
Right now I pull down the record and rails validates its contents (because I have serialized bits) I then alter one field (one of the hundred depending on X condition) and save the record again. Which I suppose writes the whole record to the database again, with no knowledge of the fact that I only changed one small bit. *(this last bit is assumption)*

Now to change one record it's sending a huge amount of data across the network, and it could be that I'm only changing one small small thing.. 
Also it's doing two queries on the database. First the select * then the update..

So my question.. are there smarter base classes that do this right, to write without read?
Top of my head I would think a setter method for each field with a bool flag for changed. 
When saving, walk the flags and where true...  Does this happen now, if so how do I make use of it?

Comment: "(this last bit is assumption)" -- that's a false assumption. ActiveRecord is smart enough to only write the changed values. It already interally has flags to keep track of which fields changed.

Comment: Actually, look at the docs for this (called "Partial Updates" btw) it's actually only in edge rails and not slated for release until Rails 4. There might be a "partial updates" plugin or gem.

Comment: Yes, its a smart update. And about making a find first, if you know what you want to update, isn't finding a record with its ID a constant time operation? how ever large the DB maybe?

Comment: @Shaunak it's not the finding I have an issue with.. it's the reading into program memory over a crappy network from a crappy server. it's the reading the record at all, since I don't give a snot what's in there.  Besides constant has never been something I find acceptable.  Constant time operations are only ok, if I need to do the operation... Else i might as well accept a sleep(100) after every line of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails models have the `update` method, which does a SQL select then an SQL update.

Its use is simple (suppose you have a model named Person)

```
Person.update(person_id, :user_name => 'New Name')
```

The drawback is that you have to know beforehand the person id.

But then, you will always have to do a query to find out that. You could write your own SQL to  change the column value, with a WHERE clause that searches for the param you have.

Rails models have the `update_all` method, which does only a SQL update without loading the data.
But I wouldn't recommend using it because it doesn't trigger any callbacks or validations that your model may have.

You could use the update_all like this:

```
Book.update_all "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'"
```

ps: examples were all taken from the Rails official documentation. If you search for update, or update_all, you'll find both methods in no time.

Take a look there, it's a good place to find out what rails can do.

[Rails API link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: I could write my own sql, but then why use activerecord at all eh?  Thanks for this.. Not sure how to create one that is contained in my model.. My view and controller shouldn't know what's going on, just that they are saving.

Comment: Sometimes you have to write your own stuff, when you have very specific problems, believe me, hehe. But if your site isn't something huge, with thousands of accesses per minute, fetching just the id from the db is just fine, use the normal methods and only worry if you really have a reason to. Listen to Knuth's wise words: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: Thanks for the update.. I might attempt to use it across all my fields. Not sure how yet though.

Comment: Good quote.. I don't agree with him though.. I prefer to think of the 1:10:100 rule. Seems it's been tested a bit more than the root of evil.  I like to think optimization first, then code it.

Comment: Oh.. I already have the ID.. so there's no fetching required :)

Comment: I think using Person.update(person_id, :user_name => 'New Name') will be executed exactly similar to find and save approach, except it will be done internally.

Comment: Yeah.. that's what I'm seeing too.  I'm wondering if I have to hack out something on my own.

Answer (score 10):

It's not obvious from the documentation, but `update_all` is the answer to this question.

```
Book.where(id: 123).update_all(title: "War and Peace")
```

results in exactly one query:

```
UPDATE `books` SET `books`.`title` = "War and Peace" WHERE `books`.`id` = 123
```

It's been a while since this question was asked, but this is so for **Rails 4/5/6**.

Comment: Loved it! The `all` part was unnecessary here: `Book.where(id: 123).update(title: "War and Peace")`. I'm using Rails 5.

Comment: For anyone on Rails 6 - use `update_all`. `update` will fire a SELECT query